# IBM Cloud Foundry Err: Unable to determine Go version to install

Tags: go, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I just created a Go runtime instance. I haven’t deployed my own application yet. The instance encountered an error during its startup, the log is:

[Unable to determine Go version to install: no match found for 1.11.x in [1.13.14 1.13.15 1.14.6 1.14.7]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRh8N.png)

The instance detail is:

```
Cloud Foundry App
Free
Region: Dallas
Plan: Lite
Runtime: Go
Domain: us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud
Space: dev
```

Comment: 1.11? Seriously ?

Comment: I have no idea what this really is about, but to me it appears like that "IBM cloud" thing insists that you use a version of the Go toolset which is one of a fixed set — presented in the error message. So you appear to be using (for whatever "using" means in this context) version 1.11.x and that cloud thing does not support it. So, the solution is to install and use a more up-to-date Go toolset. I would use 1.15 or at least 1.14.7. Please refer [here](https://golang.org/dl/) for the downloads. If you have trickier requirements for installing, please ask another question.

Comment: I just created a Go runtime instance. I haven’t deployed my own application yet. The instance encountered an error during its startup. @kostix

Answer (score 1):

This version is not supported. The [docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/go/index.html#supported_versions) point to the [release notes](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack/releases) for the list of supported Go versions. This list is:

```
go  1.13.14 cflinuxfs3
go  1.13.15 cflinuxfs3
go  1.14.6  cflinuxfs3
go  1.14.7  cflinuxfs3
go  1.15    cflinuxfs3
```

Go [1.11](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html#go1.11) was released on 2018/08/24, making it more than two years old. Use a newer version.

The above docs also tell you how to push to CloudFoundry if your deployment has an old version of the buildpack:

```
cf push my_app -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack.git
```

Comment: I just created a Go runtime instance. I haven’t deployed my own application yet. The instance encountered an error during its startup.